# Embedding JSON source code into SVG (using RDF)

Tags: svg, rdf, schema.org, rdf-xml

I am making a tool to render a program into SVG representation of the program. I would like to store input source code into SVG so that it can be reproduced if necessary. The source code is in JSON (it is a domain specific language).

I am currently setting `<metadata>` for the SVG to:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:schema="http://schema.org/">
  <schema:SoftwareSourceCode">
    <schema:text>{...}</schema:text>
  </schema:SoftwareSourceCode>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Is this a correct way to embed source code into SVG `<metadata>`? Is some other schema, entity, or property a better choice?

What I do not know how to do is how to set `rdf:datatype` for `schema:text` to inform the reader that contents are JSON?

Comment: also: define your `CURIE`s and reuse on SVG statements. See examples on: http://rhizomik.net/html/redefer/rdf2svg-form/

Comment: @JayGray can you elaborate? I am not familiar with what you are suggesting.

Comment: Take a look at the SVG code generated by Adobe `Illustrator` or Microsoft `Visio`. Each will define a vocabulary, set the `CURIE` for the vocabulary `namespace`, and then reuse the `CURIE` on SVG `<g>` statements. Those SVG documents can be harvested (parsed and processed) by - for example - an RDFa reader.

Comment: There exists the [`schema:programmingLanguage`](https://schema.org/programmingLanguage) property.  Similar question: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3981/16193

Comment: Yes, i am using programming language to specify its name. But I would also like to convey that it is encoded as JSON.